# How to get the path of the parent deploy folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, server.mappath

My application needs files outside Deploy folder And I would like to know how to set The Path with Server.MapPath("").

This is not a valid solution for me :
var FullTempPath ="C:\inetpub\TempFiles" ;

**Example:**

- C:\inetpub\ProjectFolder > Deploy
- C:\inetpub\TempFiles > Here I would like to go:

I was trying with that code but is not working:

```
 var ParentServerPath = Server.MapPath("..");

 var PartialTempPath = Path.Combine(@"/TempFiles/", key + ".js");

 var FullTempPath = ParentServerPath + PartialTempPath;
```

**The Objective:**

of that is save all JS and CSS files Minimized and Compressed generated on a folder outside my project with write permission, also I would like to know if that's a good idea, and where you're saving all that files.

Comment: "on a folder outside my project with write permission" - do you mean to say you have control of the server environment in which you can access the target folder?

Comment: Generally I like to contain all the files for one web app in one directory. It makes it easier to redeploy the app, and helps with version control (simply ignore generated files).
I store minified version in a folder named something like `content/css` and `content/js` then I have the sources in folders named `css` and `js` on the root of the project.

Comment: Hi, von. I have no control of the server enviroment I just have access on folders, Project Folder with no writing permission by the application, and a folder ProjectFolder with Writing permission

Comment: Network admins told me that For security reasons application can't write inside Deploy folder -.-' That's true??

Comment: So you're telling us that in your layout view you cannot do this: `<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>`? And that you actually have to reference it from that "folder outside your project folder"?

Comment: Yes I can do this! what i can't do is save on C:\inetpub\ProjectFolder\Content\css\213123123123213.css minimized fields generated on server side